# how to pass a default value to a form using get request?

Tags: python, html, flask

i would like to pass a value to a form through a get request. It can be done using wtforms but i'm not using that so i'd to know how to do it with request.form['test'] instead of form.test.data. Below is how it would work with wtform. I'd like to replicate that with a normal form.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    current_user.firstname= form.firstname.data 
elif request.method == 'GET':
    form.firstname.data= current_user.firstname
```

in other words, i'm making a page to update a user's data. I'd like to display what's in the database on the input form. Then when they edit it and hit update, whatever's on the form field will be updated in the DB. I'm not using WTForms. I hope there's a way to do this without it.
The form looks like this

```
<form method='post' action="/action_page">
 First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass values to the form by passing parameters to the render_template method just like this

```
firstname= " ah" 
lastname= " 1233"
return render_template("form.html", name=firstname, last=lastname)
```

then in HTML you can use jinja to put these values in the form

```
<form method='post' action="/action_page">
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname" value={{name}}>
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname" value={{last}}>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: It works but is there a way to do like the method for wtforms